# How to make JFrame transparent in JDK 1.6?

Tags: java, swing, java-6

In JDK 1.7 I use `setUndecorated(true);` and `setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` to make my frame transparent.

This works perfectly but when I change the project to 1.6 this same code just makes the frame its original blue-ish color. I don't want to make my form Opacity lower as in alpha transparent. I want to have it more like a splash screen, where GD draws SOLID non opacity lines but the surrounding is completely click-through and transparent.

What is the code in 1.6 to do this?

Answer (score 3):

**See this tutorial to understand how to make a JFrame Transparent**

http://blogofjavacrazy.blogspot.in/2007/03/transparent-window-in-java.html

**/////Edited Part//////**

I stumbled upon a neat little hack that instead of actually being transparent, it takes a screenshot and adds that little segment as the background.

**See this Link:**

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack41/index.html

Comment: sorry thats not what Im looking for, this takes a snapshot of the region behind the window then displays an illusion within the jFrame. What I need is a special color that can cause the whole jframe to be transparent while undecorated.

Answer (score 2):

> In jdk 1.6 I use setUndecorated(true); setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); to make my frame transparent. This works perfectly but when I change the project to 1.6 this same code just makes the frame its original blue-ish color.

maybe there is this issue [As of the Java Platform, Standard Edition 6 (Java SE 6) Update 10 release, you can add translucent and shaped windows to your Swing applications.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)